# How to keep secret keys a secret from sys admin?

Tags: security, amazon-s3

We have a web app which can upload files to S3. For this to be possible a configuration file is required which contains the access key id and the access secret key of my AWS account.

I am not the sys admin of the box that runs the web app. So basically this person can just grab my access secret key and eg start, stop and terminate EC2 instances, etc.

How can I keep my secret key a secret in this situation?

EDIT: To clarify, this is not about not trusting the sys admin, otherwise such a person would not get root access to the boxes (s)he maintains. Trusting a sys admin doesn't mean I have to give him/her my credit card details, the keys to my house and car, etc. That's just ridiculous.

This thing is, Amazon in giving an overview of security processes ( http://developer.amazonwebservices.com/connect/entry.jspa?externalID=1697 ) mentions:

" Within EC2, the host administrator and cloud administrator can be separate people, permitting two man rule security policies to be enforced. "

I don't see how the two can be separate though if the host administrator requires the access secret key in order to be able to upload to S3.

Comment: It may be a legal requirement that only certain people (lawyer, doctor, etc) is allowed access to the data. But it's difficult to protect a machine from root.

Comment: I'm not talking about protecting the machine from root. I'm talking about protecting the cloud infrastructure from a root user. Just because you are a root user of box 1 shouldn't give you any rights to change the ACLs of S3 buckets, terminate EC2 instances, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't have time to post detailed instructions here but I strongly recommend that you look at how to set [policies for a bucket](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucketPolicies.html) and the [access policy language](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AccessPolicyLanguage.html).  You should be able to allow unauthenticated uploads to a given bucket only from a particular IP address (associated with your EC2 instance).  You could also create a second AWS account which has no access at all except to upload to that bucket.  That way, even if they administrator ran off with your creds, they wouldn't get anything useful.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. I see it's still in beta, but I'll go for it.

Comment: +1 This new feature should solve be a good fit. I believe it has always been possible to make buckets readable to only specific AWS accounts, but the new bucket policies feature provides even greater control.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can.  If the sys admin wants your key, and has root access to the machine, they'll be able to get it.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely you should (keep your key secret).

You should provide another way to upload the files to your server. I would imagine that S3 allows you to create accounts, and if you simply have an EC2 box, you could either create a new account or install an FTP server to do the uploading.

Answer (score 0):

Being a situation where you can't trust the
Administrator is BAD. Set up your own server.

You can't hide from root!